# ReferenceError: request is not defined

Tags: node.js, express

Im trying to replicate a [facebook messenger bot](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/quick-start) but keep getting `request is not defined`.

Same code as facebook:

```
function callSendAPI(messageData) {
  request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: { access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
    method: 'POST',
    json: messageData

  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var recipientId = body.recipient_id;
      var messageId = body.message_id;

      console.log("Successfully sent generic message with id %s to recipient %s", 
        messageId, recipientId);
    } else {
      console.error("Unable to send message.");
      console.error(response);
      console.error(error);
    }
  });  
}
```

My node `server.js` looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//const request = express.request;
const PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'abc';

let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

[...]

function sendTextMessage(recipientId, messageText) {
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      text: messageText
    }
  };

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

function callSendAPI(messageData) {..}

[...]
```

Am I missing something with express? Thanks

Comment: `const request = require('request')`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This example is making use of [third-party Request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

You could also use the [native request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) like so: `require('http').request()`, if you want to, but I would say, that the *request* module is very common, and a good tool to use.

Your `request`, which is commented out, points to `express.request`. If used like `request()` will throw an error, since it's not a function. So, you should really use the Request module, or adjust the code to use native `http.request`.

#### Update 2020

The request module is deprecated now, so if you are reading this answer, use the native module or find a popular third-party library like Axios or others.

Comment: Yes I did get request is not a function. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You have **not** installed `request` module.

First install it `npm install --save request` and then **include** it `var request = require('request');`

Comment: request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 :(

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error but in a different context than yours; when I tried importing

```
import { Request } from 'express'

export class UserRequest extends Request {
  user: UserEntity;
}
```

the problem was caused because of using `class` instead of `interface`

Answer (score 0):

As for me, i got the same error when i cloned a repo that was using another node version specifically `v18.17.1` and i changed my node version from `v16...` to `v18.18.1` and it worked.